# Jasper in Grails 3.x

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

Using **Grails 3.0.12** and I need to generate a PDF report, preferably using JasperReports, but haven't found a plugin that works.

I've used **compile "org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0"** from Grails documentation but didn't work.

What plugin should I use? Or is there an alternative to generate PDF's reports in Grails 3.x?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Grails 3.2.4, and after some googling and searching for how to install Jasper Reports on Grails 3.X version without compilation error, int the oficial [Grails Plugin Page for version 3.X](https://grails.org/plugins.html)  there are the [grails-jasper](https://grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/grails-jasper) plugin, the problem is that you have to create a plugin archive using the source code and use the plugin created into your grails project as is said in the documentation. Other solution and is the one that I used, is to use the same plugin dependencies that are in the code of the grails-jasper plugin, this code is in the file [build.gradle](https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-jasper/blob/master/build.gradle) of the plugin source code, and you only have to use the necessary dependencies, the following are all that I used and its working perfectly.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7')

    compile('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.6.1') {
        exclude module: 'antlr'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'ant'
        exclude module: 'mondrian'
        exclude module: 'commons-javaflow'
        exclude module: 'barbecue'
        exclude module: 'xml-apis-ext'
        exclude module: 'xml-apis'
        exclude module: 'xalan'
        exclude module: 'groovy-all'
        exclude module: 'hibernate'
        exclude module: 'saaj-api'
        exclude module: 'servlet-api'
        exclude module: 'xercesImpl'
        exclude module: 'xmlParserAPIs'
        exclude module: 'spring-core'
        exclude module: 'bsh'
        exclude module: 'spring-beans'
        exclude module: 'jaxen'
        exclude module: 'barcode4j'
        exclude module: 'batik-svg-dom'
        exclude module: 'batik-xml'
        exclude module: 'batik-awt-util'
        exclude module: 'batik-dom'
        exclude module: 'batik-css'
        exclude module: 'batik-gvt'
        exclude module: 'batik-script'
        exclude module: 'batik-svggen'
        exclude module: 'batik-util'
        exclude module: 'batik-bridge'
        exclude module: 'persistence-api'
        exclude module: 'jdtcore'
        exclude module: 'bcmail-jdk16'
        exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk16'
        exclude module: 'bctsp-jdk16'
        exclude module: 'bcmail-jdk14'
        exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk14'
        exclude module: 'bctsp-jdk14'
        exclude module: 'xmlbeans'
        exclude module: 'olap4j'
    }

    compile('org.apache.poi:poi:3.10-FINAL')
    ...
}
```

I hope it works in your projects.

Comment: Only dependencies that have worked for me so far. I'm using Grails 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that version of the plugin only supports 2.1.0 and below.

[There is a fork of the offical Jasper plugin](https://github.com/ManvendraSK/grails-jasper) which claims to work for Grails 3 but I haven't used it myself.

You can get Jasper working in Grails 3 by adding their Java client to your build.gradle but it's a bit of a pain so I would suggest you try that other plugin first. Otherwise here is [JasperReports Server Java client Github page](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client#introduction) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I could use jasper in Grails 3 without plugin using Jasper jars.
I included the jasper dependencies in build.gradle

```
compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.2.1'

compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:6.0.0'
```

[Here](http://ezsnippet.blogspot.com/2014/07/grails-using-jasper-report-without.html) is an example how to use the jrxml files and generate required  files.